# How to use method interceptor as performance logger

Tags: java, guice

I want to use Guice and AOP support to log method execution time. I am able to print execution time to console but I would like to pass it to a different object. My code is:

GuicePerfMeter.java class

```
public class GuicePerfMeterApp {
@Inject
private RestClient client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuicePerfMeterAppModule());
    GuicePerfMeterApp app = injector.getInstance(GuicePerfMeterApp.class);

    new Result(1, app.client.waitAndGetName()); //Instead of 1 I would like to have execution time
}}
```

GuicePerfMeterAppModule.java

```
public class GuicePerfMeterAppModule extends AbstractModule {
protected void configure() {
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MeasurePerformance.class),
            new PerformanceMeter());
}}
```

MeasurePerformance.java

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MeasurePerformance {
}
```

PerformanceMeter.java

```
public class PerformanceMeter implements MethodInterceptor {
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object obj = invocation.proceed();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long executionTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Execution time: " + executionTime);
    return obj;
}}
```

RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient {

@MeasurePerformance
String waitAndGetName() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Testing";
}}
```

Result.java

```
public class Result {
private long executionTime;
private String name;

public Result(long executionTime, String name) {
    this.executionTime = executionTime;
    this.name = name;
}}
```

This are classes I created. I would like to have result object's execution time filled with execution time measured in the interceptor. Any idea guys?

Comment: Your example would only return the last execution time, can yu make sure the invocation is not triggered multiple times? As for accessing the value: many ways to do that ... keep an instance of the methodInterceptor for example. Persist the result and query it via sql. Use a publish/subscribe mechanism and fire a "new elapsed time available" event ... you should enhance your question with more detail ... how are you using the interception, where do you need access to the value, ....

Comment: Thanks, In my example I have main method which injects an object and runs annotated method. I want to create an object like MethodStat(methodResult, methodTime). It is for sure invoked multiple times...

Comment: You mentioned "keep an instance of the methodInterceptor" I create it my module and have provider which should give me the field I request for. But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you know the ElapsedTimeMeter instance in your module, why not make it injectable by using bing(ElapsedTimeMeter.class).toInstance(...);?

Comment: I meant "bind()" ...  :-)